# Exercises For Conditioning a Broken Hand

Tags: exercises, saxophone, physiology, physical-limitations, conditioning

Last August I suffered an accident where I shattered my 4th and 5th metacarpal into my wrist, severing my ACU tendon attaching to my pinky. I've been slowly relearning my right hand to play saxophone.

I'm curious if anyone knows of any exercises specifically designed for musicians recovering from such an injury. I recall a book I worked through with an instructor that had "finger buster" exercises. I have a few grip master devices, are there any other hand strength alternatives?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Consult a real physiotherapist.

Comment: Just to go along with slim here - I wouldn't take any advice (especially online) unless it came from a physical therapist.  Otherwise, you may do more damage and heal improperly.

Answer (score 2):

Shaking your hand out is good for when it gets tired.
Maybe a stress ball or, if you can handle it, a pair of these:
 [image]